# Excel Loading PDF in Userform

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

So I have been able to load a PDF into my userform (Excel 2013 on all machines) setting reference Adobe Acrobat Webrowser Control and adding control to userform.  When i open the file on another computer or try to create another excel userform and pdf I get the following errors "Run-time error-459" or "Element not found" or "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

I am using Acrobat Adobe Reader DC

I also noticed when adding control to form it labels it as Control1 instead of AcroPDF1

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With UserForm1.Control1
        .LoadFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sample.pdf" 
    End With

    UserForm1.Show 

End Sub
```

Please any help much appreciated

Comment: Please show the code that is producing the error.

Comment: I also noticed when adding control to form it labels it as Control1 instead of AcroPDF1

Comment: Ok after some reading, I understand that adobe has released an update using 64bit.  so iam guessing that is not compatible to my excel.  but i am unable to load the new control into a userform, anyone any ideas please

Comment: I'm having the same issue. No ideas yet, but I'll post back here if I find anything that works.

Comment: I'm stumped. There doesn't seem to be anything useful on this topic anywhere that I can find. The answer posted below by @fredlo2010 does not address the issue -- the control *is* available in the toolkit menu, but when an attempt it made to add it to a userform, that is the point at which the "element not found" error pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Additional Control for Adobe has been added. Also take a quick look into this post for workaround and suggestions. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=88177

[image: MyImage]

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error i found a solution.  I was currently using google chrome when experiencing this issue.  The problem was that i had a google app conflicting with the pdf.  So i disabled google apps and problem dissappeared.  Sorry comunity i didnt resopnd earlier..thanks for all the input